# Solve $f'(t)=0$ and $f'(t)=1$ using Fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I'm trying to solve $f'(t)=0$ and $f'(t)=1$ using Fourier transform, but no luck:

**a) $f'(t)=0$**

$$ f'(t)=0 \Rightarrow jwF(w)=0 
\Rightarrow \begin{cases}F(w)=0 ~ \text{if} ~ w \ne 0\\
F(0) = \text{undefined ?}
\end{cases} $$

Addendum from comments of @Winther (if I understood correctly):
In case we choice $F(0) \ne \infty$ then $f(t)=0$ that is one of the valid solutions; if we choice $F(0) = \infty$ then $f(t)=1$, another valid solution; no idea how to obtain all other possible solutions.

**b) $f'(t)=1$**

$$ f'(t)=1 \Rightarrow jwF(w)=\delta(w) 
\Rightarrow \begin{cases}F(w)=0 ~ \text{if} ~ w \ne 0\\
F(0) = \text{impossible! because left part is} =0 \text{ but right is }=\infty
\end{cases} $$

After this disaster, I've tried to proof the results (calc the derivative using Fourier transform) that I expect as the correct solutions:

**c) $f(t)=c$** (being $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$)

$$f(t)=c \Rightarrow\\
F(w)=c\delta(w) \Rightarrow\\
\mathscr{F}\{f'\}(w) = jwc\delta(w) = 0 \Rightarrow \\
f'(t) = 0 
$$

success

**d) $f(t)=t+c$**

$$f(t)=t+c\Rightarrow\\
F(w)=\delta^{(1)}(w)+c\delta(w)\Rightarrow\\
\mathscr{F}\{f'\}(w) = jw\delta^{(1)}(w)+jwc\delta(w) = jw\delta^{(1)}(w) = ~ ? 
$$

( where $\delta^{(1)}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x)$ )

blocked

Comment: $wF(w) = 0$ has the solution $F(w) = C\delta(w)$ since $w\delta(w) \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Winther: thanks for your comment. Yes, what you say is absolutelly true,  but I can also defined a $s(w)$ such as $s(w)=0 if w\ne0$, $s(0)=14$ and is also a solution of $wF(w)=0$. Moreover, I do not see how to progress in case "2)"

Comment: For the first part: yes you can add a finite value like $14$ to $F[0]$ however this does not change the integral when transforming back (only the $\delta$ and it's derivatives are able to do so). Likewise for part 2 you get $F(w) = C\delta(w) + \frac{\delta(w)}{jw}$.

Comment: @Winther: sorry, I do not know how to evaluate the inverse Fourier transform of the $s(w)$ I've described in previous comment or, at least, proof that the inverse of $s(w)$ is any constant. Please, if you have time, write an answer.

Comment: If $s(w) = 0$ except $s(0) = 14$ then the integral equals $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} s(w) e^{-jwx}{\rm d}w$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. The integrand is bounded in absolute value by $|s(0)|$ so the integrand is $\ll 2|s(0)|\epsilon$. So it has to be $0$. Maybe later. If I write up something I would like to make it a bit more rigorous than the rough outline in the comments above so only if I get time.

Comment: @Winther: thanks again. Do you mean $\mathscr{F^{-1}}{s(w)}=0$ ? . The expected solution is $f(t)=c$ not $f(t)=0$

Comment: Yes. That was my point above. This was just to show how the $s(w)$ you gave doesn't work (wasn't that what you asked about?). The $F(w)$ I gave is just a $\delta$-function which leads to the simplest integral.

Comment: Moreover, case "2)" is worst, because I've reached a contradiction.

Comment: You need to decide if you stay inside the realm of real functions or go to (tempered) distributions. In the space of distributions, $wF(w)=0$ has any distribution with support in $0$ as solution. Which is all finite linear combinations of $δ$ and its derivatives.

Comment: @LutzL: thanks for your comment. Something about case "2)" ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the formal definition of (tempered) distributions? As this question shows, thinking of distributions the way one thinks of functions can get us into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case $1$, if $F(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega\ne 0$ then $F(\omega)$ can be $k\delta(\omega)$ for any real $k$ therefore$$f(t)={k\over 2\pi}$$Case $2$
First of all, we prove the following interesting property of $\delta(.)$ and $\delta'(.)$:
$$\omega\delta'(\omega)=-\delta(\omega)$$notice that $\omega\delta'(\omega)=0\quad,\forall\omega\ne 0$ so we need to prove that $$\int_{0^-}^{0^+}\omega\delta'(\omega)d\omega=-1$$which is obvious because$$\int_{0^-}^{0^+}\omega\delta'(\omega)d\omega=\omega\delta(\omega)|_{0^-}^{0^+}-\int_{0^-}^{0^+}\delta(\omega)d\omega=-1$$which completes our proof. Now we have$$f'(t)=1$$therefore$$F(f')(\omega)=2\pi\delta(\omega)=-2\pi\omega\delta'(\omega)+2\pi j k\omega \delta(\omega)$$therefore$$F(f)(\omega)={F(f')(\omega)\over j\omega}=2\pi j\delta'(\omega)+2\pi k\delta (\omega)$$therefore$$f(t)=t+2\pi k\quad,\quad k\in\Bbb R$$